# why not working componentwillMount of the screen when i back to this screen with backHandle(hardwareBackPress)?

Tags: react-native, expo

i checking some data in component will Mount of screen. when i back to this screen with back handle,component will mount not working. 
how can fix it ?

Comment: You need to give more details : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask